# Efficient Javascript String Replacement

Tags: javascript, string, performance, replace

Hey there, I've got a block of HTML that I'm going to be using repeatedly (at various times during a users visit, not at once).  I think that the best way to accomplish this is to create an HTML div, hide it, and when needed take its innerHTML and do a replace() on several keywords.  As an example HTML block...

```
<div id='sample'>
  <h4>%TITLE%</h4>
  <p>Text text %KEYWORD% text</p>
  <p>%CONTENT%</p>
  <img src="images/%ID%/1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Would the best way to replace those keywords with dynamic data be to go...

```
template = document.getElementById('sample');
template = template.replace(/%TITLE%/, some_var_with_title);
template = template.replace(/%KEYWORD%/, some_var_with_keyword);
template = template.replace(/%CONTENT%/, some_var_with_content);
template = template.replace(/%ID%/, some_var_with_id);
```

It just feels like I've chosen a stupid way to do this.  Does anyone have any suggestions  on how to do this faster, smarter, or better in any way?  This code will be executed fairly often during a users visit, sometimes as often as once every 3-4 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I doubt there will be anything more efficient. The alternative would be splitting it into parts and then concatenating, but I don't think that would be much efficient. Perhaps even less, considering that every concatenation results in a new string which has the same size as its operands.

**Added:** This is probably the most elegant way to write this. Besides - what are you worried about? Memory usage? It's abundant and Javascript has a decent memory manager. Execution speed? Then you must have some gigantic string. IMHO this is good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  In actuality this is a much bigger block with many more replaces, so before I started I wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was missing.  Thanks again.

Comment: And there are better ways to implement it.

Answer (score 95):

It looks like you want to use a template.

```
//Updated 28 October 2011: Now allows 0, NaN, false, null and undefined in output. 
function template( templateid, data ){
    return document.getElementById( templateid ).innerHTML
      .replace(
        /%(\w*)%/g, // or /{(\w*)}/g for "{this} instead of %this%"
        function( m, key ){
          return data.hasOwnProperty( key ) ? data[ key ] : "";
        }
      );
}
```

Explanation of the code:

- Expects `templateid` to be the id of an existing element.
- Expects `data` to be an object with the data.
- Uses two parameters to replace to do the substitution:
- The first is a regexp that searches for all `%keys%` (or `{keys}` if you use the alternate version). The key can be a combination of A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and underscore _.
- The second is a anonymous function that gets called for every match.
- The anonymous function searches the data object for the key that the regexp found.
  If the key is found in the data, then the value of the key is returned and that value will be replacing the key in the final output. If the key isn't found, an empty string is returned.

Example of template:

```
<div id="mytemplate">
  <p>%test%</p>
  <p>%word%</p>
</div>
```

Example of call:

```
document.getElementById("my").innerHTML=template("mytemplate",{test:"MYTEST",word:"MYWORD"});
```

Comment: Thanks, this rocks.  I was just about ready to include a plugin like "jQuery printf" in my app, but this is all I really need :-)

Comment: Except! That it is incapable of inserting the number zero!  The replace function should really check for the value being null / undefined, rather than for truth.

Comment: rescdsk: You are right, it was incapable of inserting any falsy values like 0, NaN, false, null and undefined. I have updated the code to use `hasOwnProptery` on the object. If the property exists it will be included (even undefined). If the property doesn't exists then it will be empty space. You can change it to whatever you want by inserting text between the last `""`.

Comment: This is even a great oneliner: `document.getElementById('templateid').innerHTML.replace(/%(\w*)%/g, (m, key) => data.hasOwnProperty(key) ? data[key] : "")`

Comment: Nice. Just make it a pure function instead of a closure.

Comment: @Neutrino It is a function that returns a string.

Comment: Thanks for this wee script. Saved me some headache.

Answer (score 35):

You could probably adapt this code to do what you want:

```
let user = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "login": "john_doe",
    "password": "test",
};

let template = `Hey {firstName},
    
    You recently requested your password.
    login: {login}
    password: {password}
    
    If you did not request your password, please disregard this message.
    `;

template = template.replace(/{([^{}]+)}/g, function(keyExpr, key) {
    return user[key] || "";
});
```

You might also want to look into [JavaScriptTemplates](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates)

Comment: To avoid the additional replace call inside the handler function, just group the regex match: textbody.replace(/{([^{}]+)}/g, function(textMatched, key) { ....

Comment: wow! regex king!

Comment: To resolve deeper objects, e.g. {user.details.name}, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129960

Answer (score 25):

## [Template Replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

A quick and easy solution will be to use the [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.
It takes a second parameter that can be either a value or a function:

```
function replaceMe(template, data) {
  const pattern = /{\s*(\w+?)\s*}/g; // {property}
  return template.replace(pattern, (_, token) => data[token] || '');
}
```

###*Example*:

```
const html = `
  <div>
    <h4>{title}</h4>
    <p>My name is {name}</p>
    <img src="{url}" />
  </div>
`;

const data = {
  title: 'My Profile',
  name: 'John Smith',
  url: 'http://images/john.jpeg'
};
```

And call it like so:

```
replaceMe(html, data);
```

Comment: This is the most correct and efficient way to solve this problem. Two notes: [1] change the regex to `/\{\s*(\w+?)\\s*}/g`, as you would probably like to accept only variable-like keys and ignore any spaces in the brackets. [2] You must add a fallback to `data[token]` into empty string (`data[token]||''`), as there may be a case where the data object doesn't include a found key, in this case JS will output the string `undefined`. I will make the changes to your answer accordingly.

Comment: @SlavikMeltser Is this really the most correct and efficient way to solve this problem? Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/378001/36866 that was written here in this thread more than 10 years ago, that use the same principle but don't have the bug with the fallback? If data[token] is the number zero, it will be an empty string with your suggestion.

Comment: @SlavikMeltser, never said it's the "most correct and efficient way" but only offered a "quick and easy solution" for this challenge. Our solutions are indeed very similar (didn't notice it initially) however, I offered a robust option that can be used in different scenarios. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @some Of cores, assuming that the data is provided in strings only same way as the assumption of `data` is an object. In most of the cases this will do. This is because, the main purpose of this solution is to use it within templates mechanisms. Which means that `'0'` as a string is still positive.
But, you are right, if you want to make it even more robust, then there are a lot more features to add beyond just `hasOwnProperty`, like checking that `template` is even a string, or `data` is an object, etc. That's the beauty of it, you are always have more space to improve.

Comment: @SlavikMeltser you are correct. This is just a simple string replacement and never intended to be a full-featured template engine like Mustache, Handlebars or EJS.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is a standard way to implement a poor-man's templating system, so it's fine.

It could be worth your while to check out some JavaScript templating libraries, such as [JST](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates).

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more efficient by chaining the replaces instead of making all these interim assignments.

i.e.

```
with(document.getElementById('sample'))
{
  innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(a, A).replace(b, B).replace(c, C); //etc
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but doesn't this make readability worse? Although you might stack these calls vertically...

Comment: putting this in a with block also will break if you're replacing a keyword with a variable name that is also an object property, like "id", for instance.

Comment: *sigh* - look performance is *not* the same because chaining you create the object but do not assign it. For a chain N long you save N-1 assignments. Putting this in a with block certainly breaks if you have properties declared in scope of with, but I'm assuming as per the OP he's *not doing that*

Comment: @annakata, my benchmarks show no difference, do yours show one?. Since in JS assignment is just creating a reference, why should its time be non-neglibel?

Comment: since you were kind enough to actually test it, so did I (something I haven't done for a few years). Long story short I did 10B operations of each mode and graphed it and chaining was ~2% faster, but the S.Dev was ~10%. Conclusion: close enough not to matter any more as bigger problems exist

Comment: Finally someone used the with()  in js , I hear its  not good to use with () because  " Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details. at "
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use the [Prototype library](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template), they have nice built in templating functionality.

That would look like:

```
element.innerHTML = (new Template(element.innerHTML)).evaluate({
    title: 'a title',
    keyword: 'some keyword',
    content: 'A bunch of content',
    id: 'id here'
})
```

This would be especially nice if you were running your code in a loop due to the ease of creating JSON objects/Javascript object literals.

Still, I wouldn't expect any speed increase.

Also, you would need to change your delimiter style to `#{keyword}` rather than `%keyword%`

Answer (score 1):

This approach generates function templates that can be cached:

```
function compileMessage (message) {

  return new Function('obj', 'with(obj){ return \'' +
    message.replace(/\n/g, '\\n').split(/{{([^{}]+)}}/g).map(function (expression, i) {
      return i%2 ? ( '\'+(' + expression.trim() + ')+\'' ) : expression;
    }).join('') + 
  '\'; }');

}

var renderMessage = compileMessage('Hi {{ recipient.first_name }},\n\n' +

'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...\n\n' +

'Best Regarts,\n\n' +

'{{ sender.first_name }}');


renderMessage({
  recipient: {
    first_name: 'John'
  },
  sender: {
    first_name: 'William'
  }
});
```

returns:

```
"Hi John,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

Best Regarts,

William"
```

Answer (score 0):

Mustachejs is great for really elegant templating:

```
<div id='sample'>
  <h4>{{TITLE}}</h4>
  <p>Text text {{KEYWORD}} text</p>
  <p>{{CONTENT}}</p>
  <img src="images/{{ID}}/1.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can then use the template something like this:

```
var template = document.getElementById(templateid).innerHTML;
var newHtml = Mustache.render(template, {
    TITLE: some_var_with_title,
    KEYWORD: some_var_with_keyword,
    CONTENT: some_var_with_content,
    ID: some_var_with_id
});
document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = newHtml;
```

This especially works nicely if you are getting JSON back from an Ajax call - you can just pass it straight in to the `Mustache.render()` call.

Slight variations allow for running the same template on each the browser or the server. See https://github.com/janl/mustache.js for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://json2html.com/

It supports complex JSON objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 all modern browsers have JavaScript ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) with built-in **template literals** with replacement functionality. There is no longer a need to use external libraries or regex unless you need to support IE: https://caniuse.com/?search=template%20literals

Basic usage:

- Template literals start and end with backticks `
- Replacement values enclosed like so `${value}`  where `value` is a JS expression.
- Added benefits: no need to escape single or double quote characters and newlines are preserved.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
// Generate HTML markup for XYZ page
// @param {object} obj - parameter object with replacement values
function getMyHtml(obj) {
  if (!obj) return "";
  return `<div id='sample'>
  <h4>${obj.title}</h4>
  <p>Text text ${obj.keyword} text</p>
  <p>${obj.content}</p>
  <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/${obj.id}/52313050555_c70c17a288_m.jpg" />
</div>`
}

// example usage:
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = getMyHtml({
    title: 'Cellular Base Stations in Orbit',
    keyword: 'SpaceX',
    content: 'Tonight’s unveil: Connecting directly...',
    id: 65535
  });
```

```html
<div id='container' style='border: 1px solid blue;'>

</div>
```

(example links to a flickr photo by Steve Jurvetson)

Answer (score -2):

```
var template = "<div id='sample'><h4>%VAR%</h4><p>Text text %VAR% text</p><p>%VAR%</p><img src="images/%VAR%/1.jpg" /></div>";

var replace = function(temp,replace){
temp = temp.split('%VAR%');
for(var i in replace){
          if(typeof temp[i] != 'undefined'){
            temp[i] = temp[i] + replace[i];
          }
        }
   return temp.join('');
}

replace(template,['title','keyword','content','id'])
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: Your quotes are broken.