# How to render html from response into render function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been researching a bit and cant seem to come up with a good way of doing this.
I have a response that returns something like this:

```
    "name": "another test",
    "description": "para hacer el aseo",
    "content": "<p>Dear {{customer.firstname}} {{customer.lastname}}, bla bla bla</p>,
    "id": 6
```

I have the first name and last name from another response.
How do I render the html that comes in content and replace the placeholders with the name and last name I have?

Thank you as always any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering raw html with reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934238/rendering-raw-html-with-reactjs)

Comment: And since you have 2 questions: [string replacement in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377961/1218980)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the content value with your variable then render it with tag `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

`content = content.replace('{{customer.firstname}}', firstName).replace('{{customer.lastsname}}', lastName)`

Render it in raw HTML (not text)

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={content} />;`