# Extract values as placeholder variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

> This is the opposite problem to [Efficient JavaScript String Replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377961/efficient-javascript-string-replacement). That solution covers the  **insertion** of data into placeholders whilst this question covers the matching of strings and the **extraction** of data from placeholders.

I have a problem in understanding how to do the following in ES6 JavaScript.

I'm trying to figure out a way to match strings with placeholders and extract the contents of the placeholders as properties of an object. Perhaps an example will help.

Given the pattern:

`my name is {name} and I live in {country}`

It would match the string:

`my name is Mark and I live in England`

And provide an object:

```
{
  name: "Mark",
  country: "England"
}
```

The aim is to take a string and check against a number of patterns until I get a match and then have access to the placeholder values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [named capture groups](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html#named-capture-groups) for that problem e.g.

```js
const string = "my name is Mark and I live in England";
const regEx = /name is\s(?<name>\w+?)\b.*?live in (?<country>\w+?)\b/i;

const match = regEx.exec(string);
console.log(match?.groups);
```

Comment: Works like a dream when run in stack overflow but when I try and run the same example in Deno I don't get the groups property. I'm assuming Deno has not yet implemented this.

Comment: @MarkTyers try console.log(match?.groups); when using typescript

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if it can be done with a regex.

The way I would think about it is as follows:

- Split the template by `{` or `}`
- iterate over the latter template parts (every other one starting with index 1)
- In each iteration, get the key, its prefix, and postfix (or next prefix)
- We can then compute the start and end indices to extract the value from the string with the help of the above.

```js
const extract = (template, str) => {
  const templateParts = template.split(/{|}/);
  const extracted = {};

  for (let index = 1; index < templateParts.length; index += 2) {
    const 
      possibleKey = templateParts[index], 
      keyPrefix = templateParts[index - 1],
      nextPrefix = templateParts[index + 1];
      
    const substringStartIndex = str.indexOf(keyPrefix) + keyPrefix.length;
    const substringEndIndex = nextPrefix ? str.indexOf(nextPrefix) : str.length;
    
    extracted[possibleKey] = str.substring(substringStartIndex, substringEndIndex);
  }
  
  return extracted;
}

console.log( extract('my name is {name} and I live in {country}', 'my name is Mark and I live in England') );
```